# English and French unsubscribe pages in Pardot

Tags: pardot

Can i have English and French unsubscribe pages? I've created English and French languages pages, as well as forms, but it seems you can only have one template for the unsubscribe page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardot unfortunately allows you just one single unsubscribe page. If you use Pardot Pro or higher, you could archive multilanguage by adjusting the pages language with dynamic content based on subscribers data.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm building out a unsub template combing EN and FR elements. I don't like the cold white page and message thing we see too often, so this will be a good compromise.